# How to get My SharedPreference stored string in non Class file in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have constants.dart file and it contain all constant file including base url of my REST API. I need to change my REST API URL based on selected city which is already stored in shared preferences. I've attached my Code below.

[Here is the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHa3U.png)

Comment: please, edit your question and paste the code instead of a screenshot, more info here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.